# Entity Framework code-first change composite PK in Identity UserRoles tables

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, code-first, entity-framework-6.1

By default `UserRoles` mapped two tables `User` and `Role` by `UserId and RoleId` and have composite key on the above columns.

I customized that by adding two more entity relations:

```
public class CustomUserRole : IdentityUserRole<int>
{
        [Key]
        public int MyEntityId { get; set; }
        public virtual MyEntity MyEntity { get; set; }
}
```

I've got this migration script:

```
public override void Up()
{
            CreateTable(
                "dbo.MyEntity",
                c => new
                    {
                        Id = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                        Name = c.String(),
                    })
                .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id);           

            AddColumn("dbo.UserRoles", "MyEntityId", c => c.Int(nullable: false));
            CreateIndex("dbo.UserRoles", "MyEntityId");
            AddForeignKey("dbo.UserRoles", "MyEntityId", "dbo.MyEntity", "Id", cascadeDelete: true);
}
```

After I updated database the `UserRole` table got one more column in it called `MyEntityId` but it is being added as `FK`. I was expecting to have thriple composite primary key `UserId and RoleId and MyEntityId`.

How can I do composete `PK`: `UserId and RoleId and MyEntityId` with entity code first without touchig the database manually?

Answer (score 0):

`UserId and RoleId` are configured as PK by fluent API in `IdentityDbContext`. You need to overwrite `IdentityDbContext`'s model builder to add your own PK. Therefore override `OnModelCreating` method of your `DbContext`.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    if (modelBuilder == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("modelBuilder");
    }

    var user = modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>()
        .ToTable("AspNetUsers");
    user.HasMany(u => u.Roles).WithRequired().HasForeignKey(ur => ur.UserId);
    user.HasMany(u => u.Claims).WithRequired().HasForeignKey(uc => uc.UserId);
    user.HasMany(u => u.Logins).WithRequired().HasForeignKey(ul => ul.UserId);
    user.Property(u => u.UserName)
        .IsRequired()
        .HasMaxLength(256)
        .HasColumnAnnotation("Index", new IndexAnnotation(new IndexAttribute("UserNameIndex") { IsUnique = true }));


    user.Property(u => u.Email).HasMaxLength(256);

    // We add our PK there other configurations are Identity's default.
    modelBuilder.Entity<CustomUserRole>()
        .HasKey(r => new { r.UserId, r.RoleId, r.MyEntityId })
        .ToTable("AspNetUserRoles");

    modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserLogin>()
        .HasKey(l => new { l.LoginProvider, l.ProviderKey, l.UserId })
        .ToTable("AspNetUserLogins");

    modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserClaim>()
        .ToTable("AspNetUserClaims");

    var role = modelBuilder.Entity<MyIdentityRole>()
        .ToTable("AspNetRoles");
    role.Property(r => r.Name)
        .IsRequired()
        .HasMaxLength(256)
        .HasColumnAnnotation("Index", new IndexAnnotation(new IndexAttribute("RoleNameIndex") { IsUnique = true }));
    role.HasMany(r => r.Users).WithRequired().HasForeignKey(ur => ur.RoleId);
}
```